# Open WebUI Personalization

Tags: frontend, svelte

I've finished setting up the Open WebUI with the docker and wanted to make some changes to the landing page to have it more personalized. Looking through all the files didn't really help as I'm not that familiar with svelte and none of the files seem like the typical HTML I'm used to. If anyone has personalized there own version and would be able to direct me in the right direction would be great!

https://github.com/open-webui/open-webui  ( link to the repository )

Step by step or direction

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

***Till Now I Figured Out This One:***

To change the title from "Open WebUI" to a custom title in the backend of your application, follow these steps:

1. Navigate to the `backend/config.py` file in your project directory.
2. Look for the variable `WEBUI_NAME`.
3. Modify the value assigned to `WEBUI_NAME` to your desired custom title. For example:

   ```py
   WEBUI_NAME = "Custom Title"
   ```
4. Save the changes to the `config.py` file.
5. After making this change, you'll need to re-run your application to see the updated title reflected in the UI.

By following these steps, you can customize the title displayed in your application's UI to better suit your needs.

I hope this helps! Let me know if you have further questions.